# Looking for and dealing with collinearity in a GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity

I've got this dataset with one continuous dependent variable and two categorical explanatory variables. I'm wanting to run glms on the data but I'm finding problems with what I think is collinearity. When I analyse the data I get a bunch of NAs on the last coefficient. I can't find a way to test this kind of data for collinearity though, and particularly not for a glm. Although I'm not sure what the best thing would be to do if I did find collinearity!

Please help! This is for my undergrad dissertation and I know practically nothing about R or statistics.

By the way, the dependent variable is proportion data, hence why I am using the binomial family.

```
> summary(Model1data)
  Host                 Parasite  Replicate   Mortality     
 1      : 1   Control          : 1   A:35      Min.   :0.0000  
 MCB4865:21   Mix              :38   B:37      1st Qu.:0.0100  
 MY10   :21   S.marcescens.2170:42   C:51      Median :0.1500  
 MY14   :21   S.marcescens.D   :42             Mean   :0.2055  
 MY17   :18                                    3rd Qu.:0.3096  
 MY8    :21                                    Max.   :0.9885  
 N2     :20                                                    


> glm1 <- glm(data = Model1data, 
+            Mortality ~ Host + Parasite, family = binomial)
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
> summary(glm1)

Call:
glm(formula = Mortality ~ Host + Parasite, family = binomial, 
data = Model1data)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.86613  -0.19364  -0.08645   0.12684   1.11525  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)                 -6.801     30.015  -0.227   0.8207  
HostMCB4865                  2.654     30.069   0.088   0.9297  
HostMY10                     1.466     30.073   0.049   0.9611  
HostMY14                     1.184     30.074   0.039   0.9686  
HostMY17                     2.247     30.071   0.075   0.9404  
HostMY8                      1.523     30.072   0.051   0.9596  
HostN2                       1.955     30.071   0.065   0.9482  
ParasiteMix                  4.118      1.788   2.304   0.0212 *
ParasiteS.marcescens.2170    4.165      1.782   2.337   0.0194 *
ParasiteS.marcescens.D          NA         NA      NA       NA  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 41.499  on 122  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 15.220  on 114  degrees of freedom
AIC: 88.973

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 9
```

Also this is (I think) the contingency table

```
> table(Model1data$Host, Model1data$Parasite)

          Control Mix S.marcescens.2170 S.marcescens.D
  1             1   0                 0              0
  MCB4865       0   7                 7              7
  MY10          0   7                 7              7
  MY14          0   7                 7              7
  MY17          0   4                 7              7
  MY8           0   7                 7              7
  N2            0   6                 7              7
```

Comment: What does the contingency table of host *vs* parasite look like?  (From the single "control" count for parasites and single "1" count for hosts, it's already clear it will have some zero cells.)

Comment: Thank you Hannah--but what you posted is not a contingency table.  A contingency table summarizes all co-occurrences of the two fields, providing the count of each. Cells with zeros identify collinearities.  See the `R` help page for `table`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, sorry! OK I've had another go, thanks so much! I also see I was missing a couple of data points...

Comment: The "Control" column stands out and will cause problems: look at all those zero entries.  What exactly does this represent?  (It doesn't look like a proper control in the sense of a suitable reference for comparison, because there has been no replication.)

Comment: We did three controls for each host type, but because they were all 0 or 0.01, I averaged them. Also by giving it a different host type name so R would use it as the reference rather than one of the hosts I wanted to see the p values for them - this is what made sense at the time anyway! Would it be better to use all the controls values?

Comment: That sounds like it might be the question you *should* be asking, Hannah.  How you treat your controls in the analysis is crucial and it looks like it might be causing the technical problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right! Well I'll have a think about the controls and try to frame a new question. Thanks so much for the help whuber! :)